# go program out of memory ec2 resources too small?

Tags: go, amazon-ec2, out-of-memory

I'm wondering if I am either incorrectly writing my Go program or if my server resources too small.

I have the following code:

```
    spotXmlFile:='/var/www/html/app/public/xml/appdata.xml'
    xmlFile,err:=os.Open(spotXmlFile)
    defer xmlFile.Close()
    byteValue,_:=ioutil.ReadAll(xmlFile)
    var listings Listings
    xml.Unmarshal(byteValue,&listings)
```

It processes an xml file that is 2.5GB.

I'm using `aws ec2 t3.large` to try and process the data, which has `2 cpus` and `8GB mem`

**Whats interesting is the memory doesnt exceed 4GB but the cpu spikes to 100% and then causes the program to fail**

Here's my xml structs:

```
type Listings struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"Listings"`
    Listings []Listing `xml:"Listing"`
}

type Listing struct {
    Text    string `xml:",chardata"`
        Address struct {
            Text                   string `xml:",chardata"`
            PreferenceOrder        string `xml:"preference-order"`
            AddressPreferenceOrder string `xml:"address-preference-order"`
            FullStreetAddress      string `xml:"FullStreetAddress"`
            UnitNumber             string `xml:"UnitNumber"`
            City                   string `xml:"City"`
            StateOrProvince        string `xml:"StateOrProvince"`
            PostalCode             string `xml:"PostalCode"`
            Country                string `xml:"Country"`
        } `xml:"Address"`
        ListPrice struct {
            Text             string `xml:",chardata"`
            IsgSecurityClass string `xml:"isgSecurityClass,attr"`
            CurrencyPeriod   string `xml:"currencyPeriod,attr"`
        } `xml:"ListPrice"`
        ListingURL       string `xml:"ListingURL"`
        ProviderName     string `xml:"ProviderName"`
        ProviderURL      string `xml:"ProviderURL"`
        ProviderCategory string `xml:"ProviderCategory"`
        LeadRoutingEmail string `xml:"LeadRoutingEmail"`
        Bedrooms         string `xml:"Bedrooms"`
        Bathrooms        string `xml:"Bathrooms"`
        PropertyType     struct {
            Text             string `xml:",chardata"`
            OtherDescription string `xml:"otherDescription,attr"`
        } `xml:"PropertyType"`
        PropertySubType struct {
            Text             string `xml:",chardata"`
            OtherDescription string `xml:"otherDescription,attr"`
        } `xml:"PropertySubType"`
        ListingKey           string `xml:"ListingKey"`
        ListingCategory      string `xml:"ListingCategory"`
        ListingStatus        string `xml:"ListingStatus"`
        MarketingInformation struct {
            Text                    string `xml:",chardata"`
            PermitAddressOnInternet struct {
                Text             string `xml:",chardata"`
                IsgSecurityClass string `xml:"isgSecurityClass,attr"`
            } `xml:"PermitAddressOnInternet"`
            VOWAddressDisplay struct {
                Text             string `xml:",chardata"`
                IsgSecurityClass string `xml:"isgSecurityClass,attr"`
            } `xml:"VOWAddressDisplay"`
            VOWAutomatedValuationDisplay struct {
                Text             string `xml:",chardata"`
                IsgSecurityClass string `xml:"isgSecurityClass,attr"`
            } `xml:"VOWAutomatedValuationDisplay"`
            VOWConsumerComment struct {
                Text             string `xml:",chardata"`
                IsgSecurityClass string `xml:"isgSecurityClass,attr"`
            } `xml:"VOWConsumerComment"`
        } `xml:"MarketingInformation"`
        Photos struct {
            Text  string `xml:",chardata"`
            Photo []struct {
                Text                       string `xml:",chardata"`
                MediaModificationTimestamp struct {
                    Text             string `xml:",chardata"`
                    IsgSecurityClass string `xml:"isgSecurityClass,attr"`
                } `xml:"MediaModificationTimestamp"`
                MediaURL string `xml:"MediaURL"`
            } `xml:"Photo"`
        } `xml:"Photos"`
        DiscloseAddress       string `xml:"DiscloseAddress"`
        ListingDescription    string `xml:"ListingDescription"`
        MlsId                 string `xml:"MlsId"`
        MlsName               string `xml:"MlsName"`
        MlsNumber             string `xml:"MlsNumber"`
        LivingArea            string `xml:"LivingArea"`
        LotSize               string `xml:"LotSize"`
        YearBuilt             string `xml:"YearBuilt"`
        ListingTitle          string `xml:"ListingTitle"`
        FullBathrooms         string `xml:"FullBathrooms"`
        ThreeQuarterBathrooms string `xml:"ThreeQuarterBathrooms"`
        HalfBathrooms         string `xml:"HalfBathrooms"`
        OneQuarterBathrooms   string `xml:"OneQuarterBathrooms"`
        PartialBathrooms      string `xml:"PartialBathrooms"`
        ListingParticipants   struct {
            Text        string `xml:",chardata"`
            Participant struct {
                Text                string `xml:",chardata"`
                ParticipantKey      string `xml:"ParticipantKey"`
                ParticipantId       string `xml:"ParticipantId"`
                FirstName           string `xml:"FirstName"`
                LastName            string `xml:"LastName"`
                Role                string `xml:"Role"`
                PrimaryContactPhone string `xml:"PrimaryContactPhone"`
                OfficePhone         string `xml:"OfficePhone"`
                Email               string `xml:"Email"`
                WebsiteURL          string `xml:"WebsiteURL"`
                Licenses            struct {
                    Text    string `xml:",chardata"`
                    License struct {
                        Text            string `xml:",chardata"`
                        LicenseCategory struct {
                            Text             string `xml:",chardata"`
                            OtherDescription string `xml:"otherDescription,attr"`
                        } `xml:"LicenseCategory"`
                        LicenseNumber struct {
                            Text             string `xml:",chardata"`
                            IsgSecurityClass string `xml:"isgSecurityClass,attr"`
                        } `xml:"LicenseNumber"`
                        Jurisdiction struct {
                            Text             string `xml:",chardata"`
                            IsgSecurityClass string `xml:"isgSecurityClass,attr"`
                        } `xml:"Jurisdiction"`
                    } `xml:"License"`
                } `xml:"Licenses"`
            } `xml:"Participant"`
        } `xml:"ListingParticipants"`
        Offices struct {
            Text   string `xml:",chardata"`
            Office struct {
                Text       string `xml:",chardata"`
                OfficeKey  string `xml:"OfficeKey"`
                OfficeId   string `xml:"OfficeId"`
                OfficeCode struct {
                    Text         string `xml:",chardata"`
                    OfficeCodeId string `xml:"OfficeCodeId"`
                } `xml:"OfficeCode"`
                Name          string `xml:"Name"`
                CorporateName string `xml:"CorporateName"`
                PhoneNumber   string `xml:"PhoneNumber"`
                Fax           string `xml:"Fax"`
                Address       struct {
                    Text                   string `xml:",chardata"`
                    PreferenceOrder        string `xml:"preference-order"`
                    AddressPreferenceOrder string `xml:"address-preference-order"`
                    FullStreetAddress      string `xml:"FullStreetAddress"`
                    City                   string `xml:"City"`
                    StateOrProvince        string `xml:"StateOrProvince"`
                    PostalCode             string `xml:"PostalCode"`
                    Country                string `xml:"Country"`
                } `xml:"Address"`
                OfficeEmail string `xml:"OfficeEmail"`
                Website     string `xml:"Website"`
            } `xml:"Office"`
        } `xml:"Offices"`
        Brokerage struct {
            Text       string `xml:",chardata"`
            Name       string `xml:"Name"`
            Phone      string `xml:"Phone"`
            Email      string `xml:"Email"`
            WebsiteURL string `xml:"WebsiteURL"`
            LogoURL    string `xml:"LogoURL"`
            Address    struct {
                Text                   string `xml:",chardata"`
                PreferenceOrder        string `xml:"preference-order"`
                AddressPreferenceOrder string `xml:"address-preference-order"`
                FullStreetAddress      string `xml:"FullStreetAddress"`
                UnitNumber             string `xml:"UnitNumber"`
                City                   string `xml:"City"`
                StateOrProvince        string `xml:"StateOrProvince"`
                PostalCode             string `xml:"PostalCode"`
                Country                string `xml:"Country"`
            } `xml:"Address"`
        } `xml:"Brokerage"`
        Franchise struct {
            Text string `xml:",chardata"`
            Name string `xml:"Name"`
        } `xml:"Franchise"`
        Builder struct {
            Text string `xml:",chardata"`
            Name string `xml:"Name"`
        } `xml:"Builder"`
        Location struct {
            Text       string `xml:",chardata"`
            Latitude   string `xml:"Latitude"`
            Longitude  string `xml:"Longitude"`
            Directions string `xml:"Directions"`
            County     string `xml:"County"`
            ParcelId   string `xml:"ParcelId"`
            Community  struct {
                Text        string `xml:",chardata"`
                Subdivision struct {
                    Text             string `xml:",chardata"`
                    IsgSecurityClass string `xml:"isgSecurityClass,attr"`
                } `xml:"Subdivision"`
                Schools struct {
                    Text   string `xml:",chardata"`
                    School []struct {
                        Text           string `xml:",chardata"`
                        Name           string `xml:"Name"`
                        SchoolCategory string `xml:"SchoolCategory"`
                        District       struct {
                            Text             string `xml:",chardata"`
                            IsgSecurityClass string `xml:"isgSecurityClass,attr"`
                        } `xml:"District"`
                    } `xml:"School"`
                } `xml:"Schools"`
            } `xml:"Community"`
        } `xml:"Location"`
        DetailedCharacteristics struct {
            Text       string `xml:",chardata"`
            Appliances struct {
                Text      string   `xml:",chardata"`
                Appliance []string `xml:"Appliance"`
            } `xml:"Appliances"`
            ArchitectureStyle struct {
                Text             string `xml:",chardata"`
                OtherDescription string `xml:"otherDescription,attr"`
            } `xml:"ArchitectureStyle"`
            HasBarbecueArea string `xml:"HasBarbecueArea"`
            CoolingSystems  struct {
                Text          string `xml:",chardata"`
                CoolingSystem string `xml:"CoolingSystem"`
            } `xml:"CoolingSystems"`
            ExteriorTypes struct {
                Text         string `xml:",chardata"`
                ExteriorType string `xml:"ExteriorType"`
            } `xml:"ExteriorTypes"`
            HasFireplace   string `xml:"HasFireplace"`
            FloorCoverings struct {
                Text          string   `xml:",chardata"`
                FloorCovering []string `xml:"FloorCovering"`
            } `xml:"FloorCoverings"`
            HeatingFuels struct {
                Text        string `xml:",chardata"`
                HeatingFuel string `xml:"HeatingFuel"`
            } `xml:"HeatingFuels"`
            HeatingSystems struct {
                Text          string   `xml:",chardata"`
                HeatingSystem []string `xml:"HeatingSystem"`
            } `xml:"HeatingSystems"`
            IsNewConstruction string `xml:"IsNewConstruction"`
            HasPool string `xml:"HasPool"`
            NumFloors         string `xml:"NumFloors"`
            ParkingTypes      struct {
                Text        string `xml:",chardata"`
                ParkingType string `xml:"ParkingType"`
            } `xml:"ParkingTypes"`
            HasPatio  string `xml:"HasPatio"`
            RoofTypes struct {
                Text     string `xml:",chardata"`
                RoofType string `xml:"RoofType"`
            } `xml:"RoofTypes"`
            RoomCount string `xml:"RoomCount"`
            Rooms     struct {
                Text string   `xml:",chardata"`
                Room []string `xml:"Room"`
            } `xml:"Rooms"`
            HasVaultedCeiling string `xml:"HasVaultedCeiling"`
        } `xml:"DetailedCharacteristics"`
        ModificationTimestamp struct {
            Text             string `xml:",chardata"`
            IsgSecurityClass string `xml:"isgSecurityClass,attr"`
        } `xml:"ModificationTimestamp"`
        Disclaimer struct {
            Text             string `xml:",chardata"`
            IsgSecurityClass string `xml:"isgSecurityClass,attr"`
        } `xml:"Disclaimer"`    
}
```

Here's my run output:

```
fatal error: runtime: out of memory

runtime stack:
runtime.throw(0x4f44be, 0x16)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:774 +0x72
runtime.sysMap(0xc104000000, 0x100000000, 0x5cc478)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mem_linux.go:169 +0xc5
runtime.(*mheap).sysAlloc(0x5b4dc0, 0x100000000, 0x7ba23, 0x0)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:701 +0x1cd
runtime.(*mheap).grow(0x5b4dc0, 0x80000, 0xffffffff)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mheap.go:1252 +0x42
runtime.(*mheap).allocSpanLocked(0x5b4dc0, 0x80000, 0x5cc488, 0x100000081)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mheap.go:1163 +0x291
runtime.(*mheap).alloc_m(0x5b4dc0, 0x80000, 0x400101, 0xc0000344c8)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mheap.go:1015 +0xc2
runtime.(*mheap).alloc.func1()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mheap.go:1086 +0x4c
runtime.(*mheap).alloc(0x5b4dc0, 0x80000, 0x7ffd80010101, 0x433515)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mheap.go:1085 +0x8a
runtime.largeAlloc(0xfffffe00, 0xc000010101, 0xc000000180)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:1138 +0x97
runtime.mallocgc.func1()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:1033 +0x46
runtime.systemstack(0x452364)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:370 +0x66
runtime.mstart()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:1146

goroutine 1 [running]:
runtime.systemstack_switch()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:330 fp=0xc00006ac10 sp=0xc00006ac08 pc=0x452460
runtime.mallocgc(0xfffffe00, 0x4c56e0, 0x1, 0x0)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:1032 +0x895 fp=0xc00006acb0 sp=0xc00006ac10 pc=0x40bb85
runtime.makeslice(0x4c56e0, 0xfffffe00, 0xfffffe00, 0x0)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/slice.go:49 +0x6c fp=0xc00006ace0 sp=0xc00006acb0 pc=0x43dc8c
bytes.makeSlice(0xfffffe00, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /usr/local/go/src/bytes/buffer.go:229 +0x77 fp=0xc00006ad48 sp=0xc00006ace0 pc=0x4673d7
bytes.(*Buffer).grow(0xc00006ae70, 0x200, 0x40000000)
        /usr/local/go/src/bytes/buffer.go:142 +0x15b fp=0xc00006ad98 sp=0xc00006ad48 pc=0x466ecb
bytes.(*Buffer).ReadFrom(0xc00006ae70, 0x50fc00, 0xc000082018, 0xc000082018, 0x3, 0x0)
        /usr/local/go/src/bytes/buffer.go:202 +0x4b fp=0xc00006ae08 sp=0xc00006ad98 pc=0x4671cb
io/ioutil.readAll(0x50fc00, 0xc000082018, 0x200, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /usr/local/go/src/io/ioutil/ioutil.go:36 +0x100 fp=0xc00006aea8 sp=0xc00006ae08 pc=0x47b380
io/ioutil.ReadAll(...)
        /usr/local/go/src/io/ioutil/ioutil.go:45
main.main()
        /var/www/html/spot/importdata/main.go:36 +0xbf fp=0xc00006af60 sp=0xc00006aea8 pc=0x4ad63f
runtime.main()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:203 +0x21e fp=0xc00006afe0 sp=0xc00006af60 pc=0x42bfbe
runtime.goexit()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1357 +0x1 fp=0xc00006afe8 sp=0xc00006afe0 pc=0x4543b1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading the whole file in memory and then unmarshaling it, which is going to use a lot of additional memory that you don't really need. Try this, see what happens:

```
spotXmlFile:='/var/www/html/app/public/xml/appdata.xml'
xmlFile,err:=os.Open(spotXmlFile)
defer xmlFile.Close()
var listings Listings
xml.NewDecoder(xmlFile).Decode(&listings)
```

Using decoder, it will parse and unmarshal the underlying file as it reads.

If you need only part of the file and want to further optimize this, you can decode the file using the decoder token by token, and extract the part you need.